# Laravel hasManyThrough Eloquent query failing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models:

Client, Store, Format

A client has many stores, and a store has one format.

So, I would like to get all Formats from Client.

```
In Store table, I have client_id, format_id

in Format table, I have no direct relationship, I have plan_id

In Plan table, I have client_id.

In Client table, I have no useful relationship
```

I need to get all formats of a client,

So I need to create a relationship $client->formats

So basically,I want to do a hasManyThrough relationship,

```
    class Client extends Model {

        protected $table = 'client';
        protected $primaryKey = 'clientid';



        public function formats()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(Format::class,Store::class, 'clientid', 'storeid');
        }

    }
```

But I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'format.storeid' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `format`.*, `store`.`clientid` from `format` inner join `store` on `store`.`storeid` = `format`.`storeid` where `store`.`clientid` = 58)
```

I'm a little bit stuck in this relation, any idea how to fix it????

Comment: This sounds more like a many-to-many relationship between Client and Format with Store being the pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship

```
class Client extends Model {

    protected $table = 'client';
    protected $primaryKey = 'clientid';



    public function formats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Format::class, 'Store_table', 'client_id', 'format_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems to be working... I still don't understand all about Eloquent... Tx for your help!

Comment: Saludos de México!

Comment: Jaja lol claro gracias e igual saludos desde México a México xD!